# Angular 4 Cannot match any routes in production build only

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 4 (4.4.4) ng-cli app.

Here are my routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: DefaultComponent },
    { path: 'somethingcool/:val', component: DefaultComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'some-where', component: SomeOtherComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Inside `SomeOtherComponent` i access optional query parameters like so:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.route.queryParams.subscribe(p => {
      this.someValue = p['some-parameter'] == "true" || false;
    });
  }
```

When i debug the app locally (`ng serve`) this works perfectly.

When i do a `ng build --prod` i am instead getting a `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'some-where'`

EDIT: Specifically, if i go to `https://myurl/some-where` it works, but `https://myurl/some-where?some-parameter=true` doesn't. If i host them locally (`http://localhost:4200`) then this works.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the documentation about [ng build](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/build.md).

At the end, you have all the available parameter and you should use `--base-href` or `-bh`.

This option allows you to specify the root URL of the app so here you should do :

```
ng build -bh 'myurl/some-where'
```

Comment: How is that related? Myurl is the base url, some-where is one of the routes only

Comment: My bad I haven't seen that 'some-where' is an Angular route... but still, you should do `ng build -bh 'myurl'`